# Is there a way to connect to Laptops via wireless to transfer files without router?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-transfer

I have read that it is possible to connect them with ad-hoc, but I am not sure if files can be transferred. Also, I cant seem to find any information if Win 7 and Win 8 is compatible for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be the point of connecting computers ad-hoc if you couldn't use it?
Yes, you can transfer files. You set it up in Network and Sharing center.

Or use a wireless access point.